# useColorMode not working for Chakra UI Footer Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

The ColorMode hook has been working for all my code so far when it comes to customizing my compoenents for Chakra UI's dark and light modes. However, when I tried to do the same with my footer, it does not work and I do not know why.

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Stack, Text, useColorMode } from "@chakra-ui/react";

export default function Footer() {
  const { colorMode } = useColorMode();

  return (
    <Stack
      direction="row"
      width="full"
      height="75px"
      bgColor={colorMode === "light" ? "#EF820D" : "orange.400"}
      justify="space-between"
    >
      <Text
        paddingTop="25px"
        paddingLeft="20px"
        align="left"
        color={colorMode === "light" ? "whiteDark" : "black"}
      >
        Created by Siddhardh Palaparthi, 2021
      </Text>

      <Text
        paddingTop="25px"
        paddingRight="20px"
        align="right"
        color={colorMode === "light" ? "whiteDark" : "black"}
      >
        Contact Me: siddu.palaparthi@gmail.com
      </Text>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Show the component where you render `<Footer/>` - I'm willing to bet it's "not working" because `Footer` it's not inside of the `ChakraProvider`, like all your other components.

Comment: Hello, my page is a single scroll page where I just have all my other sections on one landing page. So I render footer on that landing page. On that same page are other components where I use colormode the same way and it works. I put my ChakraProvider in App.js, where it encapsulates my landing page.

Comment: If `Footer` is indeed inside the provider, then there's no reason why it wouldn't work. What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Do you mean if you toggle the color mode somewhere else your footer doesn't change? If that's the case, it's because it's not inside the Provider. Alternative problem: Maybe you have multiple `ChakraProvider`'s - One that wraps your whole App, and one that wraps everything except your footer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that changing whiteDark to white fixed my issue but I am not sure why, as whiteDark worked in my header. Thank you.